# Sum based on multiple drop-down list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go49t.jpg)

Column A4 to A8 have drop down list option from Rune 1.
Column B4 to B8 have drop down list option from Rune 1.

Column D4 to D8 have drop down list option from Rune 2.
Column E4 to E8 have drop down list option from Rune 2.

I need the sum of the total VALUE of a specific STAT chosen on both RUNES and don't know the formula.

Please need help.

Answer (score 0):

If the Stat can be repeated in the following rows, you can use:

```
=SUMIF($A$4:$A$8,G4,$B$4:$B$8)+SUMIF($D$4:$D$8,G4,$E$4:$E$8)
```

the references correspond to your picture
Sumif will check in column A for the corresponding Stat and add the corresponding Value